# Move Movies of different Encodes to a common Folder with original Movie Title

Tags: bash

So I am having this situation...
I have many files in my Folder which will look like this

```
Iron.Man.2008.1440p.UHD.US.BluRay.x265.HDR.DD5.1-Pahe.in
Iron Man 2008.720p.BrRip.x264.YIFY
Iron.Man.2008.US.RERiP.720p.UHD.BluRay.x264-Pahe.in
Iron.Man.2008.Open.Matte.720p.WEB-HD.x264-Pahe.in
Iron.Man.2008.US.RERiP.1080p.UHD.BluRay.x264.DD5.1-Pahe.in
The.Incredible.Hulk.2008.REMASTERED.1080p.BluRay.x264.DD5.1-Pahe.in
The.Incredible.Hulk.2008.REMASTERED.720p.BluRay.x264-Pahe.in
The.Avengers.2012.2160p.10bit.HDR.BluRay.8CH.x265.HEVC-PSA
The.Avengers.2012.1080p.10bit.BrRip.6CH.x265.HEVC-PSA
The.Avengers.2012.720p.10bit.BrRip.6CH.x265.HEVC-PSA
```

So I have multiple movies which are same - but of different encoders and different quality.

What I am trying to achieve is move all these different encodes to a common folder with original Movie name as Title

For example

```
Iron.Man.2008
  Iron.Man.2008.1440p.UHD.US.BluRay.x265.HDR.DD5.1-Pahe.in
  Iron Man 2008.720p.BrRip.x264.YIFY
  Iron.Man.2008.US.RERiP.720p.UHD.BluRay.x264-Pahe.in
  Iron.Man.2008.Open.Matte.720p.WEB-HD.x264-Pahe.in
  Iron.Man.2008.US.RERiP.1080p.UHD.BluRay.x264.DD5.1-Pahe.in
The.Incredible.Hulk.2008
  The.Incredible.Hulk.2008.REMASTERED.1080p.BluRay.x264.DD5.1-Pahe.in
  The.Incredible.Hulk.2008.REMASTERED.720p.BluRay.x264-Pahe.in
The.Avengers.2012
  The.Avengers.2012.2160p.10bit.HDR.BluRay.8CH.x265.HEVC-PSA
  The.Avengers.2012.1080p.10bit.BrRip.6CH.x265.HEVC-PSA
  The.Avengers.2012.720p.10bit.BrRip.6CH.x265.HEVC-PSA
```

I had tried to run this as a bat file..it created Folders but it moved files based on their original File name..each encode were moved into their own particular folder

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
md "%%~na" 2>nul
move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
pause
```

I am open for any solution in windows or Linux

Thank you

Comment: Hello Roshan, would you please share your code, so we may discuss the issues that you may be having?

Comment: @echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
md "%%~na" 2>nul
move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
pause

Comment: The second Iron man does not have a dot in between from the beginning?

Comment: Yes it is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with bash using the regex pattern matching with `BASH_REMATCH`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A uniq

##: The script should be inside the directory where the video files are
for files in ./*; do
  if [[ $files =~ ^(.*[[:digit:]]{4})\.(.+)$ ]]; then
    no_space=${BASH_REMATCH[1]// /.}
    uniq[$no_space]=1
    all_files+=("${BASH_REMATCH[0]}")
    first_part+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
  fi
done

for j in "${!uniq[@]}"; do
  mkdir -p "$j" || exit
  dir+=("$j")
done

for i in "${!all_files[@]}"; do
  for k in "${dir[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${first_part[$i]// /.} == $k ]]; then
      mv -v  "${all_files[$i]}" "$k" || exit
    fi
  done
done
```

---

Version 2.0 which try to match all the new file format/pattern.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A uniq

for files in ./*; do
  if [[ $files =~ ^(.*\(?[[:digit:]]{4}\)?)[\.[[:blank:]]]?(.+)$ ]]; then
    no_space=${BASH_REMATCH[1]// /.}
    uniq[$no_space]=1
    all_files+=("${BASH_REMATCH[0]}")
    first_part+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
  fi
done

for j in "${!uniq[@]}"; do
  mkdir -p "${j//[)(]}" || exit
  dir+=("$j")
done

for i in "${!all_files[@]}"; do
  for k in "${dir[@]}"; do
  if [[ ${first_part[$i]// /.} == $k ]]; then
    mv -v  "${all_files[$i]}" "${k//[)(]}" || exit
  fi
  done
done
```

- Just try it out for a couple of sample files and not the whole 4k files like what you have now.
- also make a backup of the files just in case.

Comment: I must add that it didnt move certain files because some file names were not seperated by . instead by space..posting some samples below
`47.Ronin.(2013).[1080p.x265.10bit.S74.Joy]`
`Schumer Growing (2019) (1080p NF WEB-DL x265 YOGI)`
`Your Friend the Rat 2007 1080p Blu-ray DD-EX 5.1 HEVC- DDR[EtHD]`
`X-Men 2000 (1080p x265 10bit Tigole)`

Comment: @roshan, added the new script, you should add the other video format at your post/question.

Comment: Thats so nice of you...Dumb me used bulk rename utility and replaced all spaces with dots and used your older script..it worked fine,
Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

Since you also tagged this `PowerShell`, here's a solution:

```
$sourceFolder = 'D:\Test'          # where the files are now
$destination  = 'D:\Movies'        # where the subfolders storing the files should be created

$regex = '^(\D+[.\s]\d{4})\..*'    # see explanation below
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match $regex }) | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $subFolder = ([regex]$regex).Match($_.BaseName).Groups[1].Value -replace '\s', '.'
        $targetDir = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $subFolder
        # create the subfolder if it does not yet exist
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $targetDir -PathType Container)) {
            $null = New-Item -Path $targetDir -ItemType Directory
        }
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetDir
    }
```

Regex details:

```
^           # Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
(           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \D       # Match a single character that is not a digit 0..9
      +     # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [.\s]    # Match a single character present in the list below
            # The character “.”
            # A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   \d       # Match a single digit 0..9
      {4}   # Exactly 4 times
)
\.          # Match the character “.” literally
.           # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *        # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Comment: Hi
First of all Thanks
This seems to be working..but i feel that its a bit slow....
After 15 mins..it created one Folder and moved one file inside it..
The issue is that i have 4k files to arrange this way

Comment: it worked instantly for the first file and after that nothing happened..Thanks