# Move files to respective folders based on their file name

Tags: bash

I am having a bit of problem in arranging my files

So I have around 3000 movies named as per below, in that there are multiple movies which are the same but are having different resolutions. Here is a sample:

```
Toy Story 4 (2019) - 720p h265 10 AAC 6ch.mkv
Toy Story 4 (2019) - 1080p h265 10 AAC 6ch.mkv
Toy Story 4 (2019) - 2160p h265 10 AAC 6ch.mkv
X Men Apocalypse (2016) - 1080p h265 10 AAC 8ch.mkv
X Men Apocalypse (2016) - 720p h265 10 AAC 8ch.mp4
```

What I would like to Have is to move all common movies to a common Folder. Like this

```
Toy Story 4 (2019)
  Toy Story 4 (2019) - 720p h265 10 AAC 6ch.mkv
  Toy Story 4 (2019) - 1080p h265 10 AAC 6ch.mkv
  Toy Story 4 (2019) - 2160p h265 10 AAC 6ch.mkv
X Men Apocalypse (2016)
  X Men Apocalypse (2016) - 1080p h265 10 AAC 8ch.mkv
  X Men Apocalypse (2016) - 720p h265 10 AAC 8ch.mp4
```

PS: All of my movies are named this way

I had a similar problem before, and it was solved - [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151413/move-movies-of-different-encodes-to-a-common-folder-with-original-movie-title)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A uniq

##: The script should be inside the directory where the video files are
for files in *; do
  if [[ $files =~ ^(.*[[:digit:]]{4})\.(.+)$ ]]; then
    no_space=${BASH_REMATCH[1]// /.}
    uniq[$no_space]=1
    all_files+=("${BASH_REMATCH[0]}")
    first_part+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
  fi
done

for j in "${!uniq[@]}"; do
  mkdir -p "$j"
  dir+=("$j")
done

for i in "${!all_files[@]}"; do
  for k in "${dir[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${first_part[$i]// /.} == $k ]]; then
      mv -v  "${all_files[$i]}" "$k"
    fi
  done
done
```

So I tried the same solution, unfortunately, it didn't work at all

I got this error

```
“$'\r': command not found”
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Ps: I also tried software like `Tinymediamanager`, but it could move only one movie, not all of them

Comment: I am confused, the question you linked to has `python-3.x`, `linux`, `windows`, `bash` and `powershell` tags and a `batch-file` in the code. You accepted the `bash` answer. Here you are doing the same `bash`, `python` `powershell` and `batch-file` in the tags and no code at all, making this question off-topic in its entirety.

Comment: i am sorry, I am pretty new to Stack Overflow
I will try to add the code I used and will try to be more specific..Thank you

Comment: Thanks for editing, I will retract my close vote, please also indicate what issue you have with the current script as _"didn't work at all"_ does not really indicate an actual issue.

Comment: `$'\r' is the windows CR character. Seems like your script somehow touched a windows system and got converted. Unconvert is with `dos2unix myScript`. In any case, it can't hurt to run that cmd. If that doesn't fix it, please add that information to the body of your Q (maybe near the top). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you!
That saved me...I converted bas into UNIX and ran it
And alas!
It worked very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution

In my previous post..one User had given me another bash script to use with any other instances..But when I ran it gave me error..because it was not in UNIX format..I used Notepad ++ to change the Format and alas!..it worked

Thank you everyone for your Suggestion and Thank you [Jetchisel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4452265/jetchisel)

Here is the Solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A uniq

for files in *; do
  if [[ $files =~ ^(.*\(?[[:digit:]]{4}\)?)[\.[[:blank:]]]?(.+)$ ]]; then
    no_space=${BASH_REMATCH[1]// /.}
    uniq[$no_space]=1
    all_files+=("${BASH_REMATCH[0]}")
    first_part+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
  fi
done

for j in "${!uniq[@]}"; do
  mkdir -p "${j//[)(]}"
  dir+=("$j")
done

for i in "${!all_files[@]}"; do
  for k in "${dir[@]}"; do
  if [[ ${first_part[$i]// /.} == $k ]]; then
    mv -v  "${all_files[$i]}" "${k//[)(]}"
  fi
  done
done
```

Run this inside the Folder where your Files are

This is from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151413/move-movies-of-different-encodes-to-a-common-folder-with-original-movie-title)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that unless you need the added complication for a reason, just keep it as simple as possible.

The code is slower and less efficient but a lot easier to read if you do them individually.

```
for f in *.mkv
do d="${f% - *}"
   mkdir -p "$d"
   mv "$f" "$d/"
done
```

If you want to speed it up -

```
for f in *.mkv
do [[ -e "$f" ]] || continue
   d="${f% - *}"
   mkdir -p "$d/"
   mv "$d"*.mkv "$d"
done
```

Does that not accomplish what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you @Paul Hodges

I will try this and Let you Know