# Move Files with common naming convention to consolidated folders

Tags: bash, powershell, file, directory, organization

Similar to this: [Move Movies of different Encodes to a common Folder with original Movie Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151413/move-movies-of-different-encodes-to-a-common-folder-with-original-movie-title)

I have a series of PSB and Png export files I wanted all moved to common directories. I don't care if its PowerShell or Bash. I tried both the solutions on that link above, but neither worked. Mine at least appears to be a simpler problem though that I can't find a solution to....

I have several files that I just have the following formatting:

Filename1.psb
Filename2.psb
filename3.psb
Filename4final.gammaOMega.psb
Example3.psb
Example4.png

They might not all be in the same folder, nor all have common casing and may have random characters or spacing in the file names. The number Zero, a space, or special character might sometimes be used as well in place of a number. However, I can guarantee the first 4-7 chracters of the naming conventions are the same letters on all files. They are all in my Onedrive folder though, just might not be all in the same subfolder.

My goal is to consolidate all of the files to folders to common Folders as follows:

| File | Folder |
| --- | --- |
| Filename1.psb | Filename |
| Filename2.psb | Filename |
| filename3.psb | Filename |
| Filename4final.gammaOMega.psb | Filename |
| Example3.psb | Example |
| Example4.png | Example |

Because I occasionally slip up and use the same name of file that may be a different revision, rather than overwriting, I prefer to keep both copies instead and rename the later file with .1.psb, .2.psb, etc and so forth. The file can be overwritten if the name, size, and date modified are identical.

What would be the best solution for this in Windows 10? I wouldn't even care if there was a simply batch file solution even.

Would it also be possible to set up a flag to ignore certain directories within the OneDrive folder as well?

Comment: Where would `FilenameX1.png` go if it existed please?

Comment: In that example, it would go into the "FilenameX" folder.

Comment: In this case @NathanGagne the @tshiono answer will works fine. I've updated my answer to add more clarity on the statements it answer. For example when we said yesterday "If you want to dynamically create those folder when two files got something in common on the name" "Yup that's what I'm saying." => `FilenameX` would move on `Filename` directory.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER this answer is based on those statements

> If you want to dynamically create those folder when two files got something in common on the name

> Yup that's what I'm saying.

If you want to only extract the alphabetical part of the filenames before the first digit to make it a folder name, it's more simpler and you can go for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65518260/2900196).

But if you want to dynamically generate folder on what two filenames have in common regardless of if this is alphabetical or numerical characters, you could try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change those variable according to your wanted path
# You can just export them before starting this script to override those default values
[[ -z $FOLDERS_PATH ]] && FOLDERS_PATH="."
[[ -z $FILES_PATH ]] && FILES_PATH="."

declare -a FOLDER_NAMES

# Convert a string into PascalCase
to_pascal_case() {
  str="${1,,}"
  echo "${str^}"
}
  
# Get a list of directory to create based on what file's names got in common
directories_to_create() {
  find "${FILES_PATH}" -type f|sed -e 'N;s/^\(.*\).*\n\1.*$/\1/'|awk -F '/'  '
   BEGIN {
    previous_file="to_ignore"
   } 
   ($NF ~ ".+") {
     file=tolower($NF); 
     files[file]=file
   } 
   END {
     asorti(files, sorted_files); 
     for (i in sorted_files) {
       file=sorted_files[i]; 
       if(!(file ~ previous_file".*")) {
         print file
       }
       previous_file=file
     }
   }'
}

# Create the directory dynamically and build an array of those directories
create_directories() {
  while read -r folder_name; do
    formatted_folder_name="$(to_pascal_case "${folder_name}")"
    mkdir -p "${FOLDERS_PATH}/${formatted_folder_name}"
    FOLDER_NAMES+=("${formatted_folder_name}")
  done < <(directories_to_create)
}

# Move if the filename match the directory name
move_if_it_match() {
  file_name="${1}"
  folder_name="${2}"
  complete_file_path="${3}"
  [[ ${file_name,,} =~ ^"${folder_name,,}".* ]] && mv "${complete_file_path}" "${FOLDERS_PATH}/${folder_name}"
}

# Moving the files if their name match with the folders (case insensitive match)
move_files() {
  find "${FILES_PATH}" -type f|while read -r file_path; do
    file_name="$(basename "$file_path")"
    for folder_name in "${FOLDER_NAMES[@]}"; do
      move_if_it_match "${file_name}" "${folder_name}" "${file_path}"
    done
  done
}

# Main program
create_directories
move_files
```

Demo:

```
$ find . -type f
./Example3.psb
./Example4.png
./Example5.png
./move.sh
./filename3.psb
./Filename1.psb
./Filename2.psb
./Filename4final.gammaOMega.psb
./Example with_spaces.mp4
$ bash move.sh 
$ find . -type f
./move.sh
./Example/Example3.psb
./Example/Example4.png
./Example/Example5.png
./Example/Example with_spaces.mp4
./Filename/filename3.psb
./Filename/Filename1.psb
./Filename/Filename2.psb
./Filename/Filename4final.gammaOMega.psb
```

Comment: When I run that, it will only just generate two folders named "FileName" and "Example" My apologies, the files aren't actually named that, those are just examples I used, the names of the files could be anything. Only commonality is they are either psb or png files and the the common files all at least have the same 4-7 characters at the beginning of the file name.

Is there any way to have those folder names themselves a context variable to the file's name?

Also the only way I could get it to run was add another "done" at the end.  It also errors out with the following:

Comment: basename: extra operand ‘Photoshop’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.

Comment: @NathanGagne You just have to change the list `folder_names` with whatever you want as folders. If you want to dynamically create those folder when two files got something in common on the name, it would be something else indeed. In this case you'll have to explain what you want a little bit more (with more specific rules for example like the min of char in common, the priority rules, etc).

Comment: @NathanGagne for your `basename` error, my guess is it's because some of your files contains spaces in their names. So I've updated my answer a little bit to deal with this case.

Comment: Yup that's what I'm saying. Dynamically generate the folder based on it's file name, put in folder of same common name. Move other files with similar naming convention. 4-7 leading characters of each file name would be the same, anything after could be different.

Comment: I tryed running that, it didnt appear to generate any folders. I tryed different forced folder destination directories too.

Comment: @NathanGagne I could not guess what's your problem without any more context (input, your own script, output with errors messages when they comes out, expected output). Maybe it's related to Windows, also check each command versions and if each is working the same way: `bash`, `find`, `sed`, `awk`, `mkdir`... and try to debug step by step the script on your system.

Comment: @NathanGagne I've edited my answer to split some part in functions to make easier the debugging so you'll be able to test the `directories_to_create` function alone for example. May the force be with you.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    base=${f##*/}; base=${base//[^a-zA-Z]*}     # extract "basename"
    dir=${base,,}; dir=${dir^}                  # convert to Camelcase
    mkdir -p -- "$dir"                          # create the directory
    mv -- "$f" "$dir"                           # move to the directory
done < <(find . -type f \( -iname "*.psb" -o -iname "*.png" \) -print0)
```

- The `find ..` statement finds the specified files recursively and feed the
  filenames to the `while` loop delimited with the null character (to allow
  whitespaces and other special characters in the filename).
- The `-d ""` option tells `read` to split the input on the null characters.
- `${f##*/}` removes directory path.
- `${base//[^a-zA-Z]*}` removes non-alphabetical character and the following
  characters.
- `${base,,}` converts the characters to lowercase.
- `${dir^}` converts the first character to uppercase.